# Class as a Generic in java

Tags: java, list, class, generics

I know how to use generics in java but if an instance is given as

```
List<someclass> ai = new List<someclass>();
```

How can I use the list in this case? How can I access and modify elements in the class?

Please provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it mostly like any non-generic list.
Here is an example with a list of Strings that shows inserting, getting and deleting elements as well as checking for their existence:

```
package example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("foo");
        list.add("bar");

        // Get/extract the first element
        // You can then call methods on
        // that element, e.g. list.get(0).toUpperCase(...)
        String firstElement = list.get(0);
        System.out.println("First Element: " + firstElement);

        // Remove the first element
        list.remove("foo");
        firstElement = list.get(0);
        System.out.println("First Element after delete: " + firstElement);

        // Check whether the list contains an object
        if (list.contains("bar")) {
            System.out.println("List contains bar.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("List doesn't contain bar.");
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
First Element: foo
First Element after delete: bar
List contains bar.
```

---

You can use generics in method parameters to only accept lists that contain certain types of elements:

```
package example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("foo");
        list.add("bar");
        printAll(list);
    }

    public static void printAll(List<String> list) {
        for (String str : list) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
foo
bar
```

---

The following however is invalid, because you would try to insert an Integer into a Strings-only list:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line of code you provided is not correct. `List` is an interface and interfaces cannot be instantiated. If you want to define a variable of type `List<ClassName>`, you have to initialize it with a constructor of a subclass. The most common subclass for the `List<>` interface is the `ArrayList<>` class. So your line of code should be:

```
List<SomeClass> ai = new ArrayList<SomeClass>();
```

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceAsType.html) you can find more information for interfaces.